# Discord js v12: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

no clue why its not working, can somebody help me? I despair.

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    var roles = message.author.roles
    let roleID = '1234567890';
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ttt')) {
        roles.add(roleID);          
    }
});

The Error is the same like in the title.
        roles.add(roleID);
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Hello emirate, please let us know how you have resolved your problem. Your solution can help other people who have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property `roles` of `message.author`. You may want to look at `message.member` instead, which has that property.

Relevant Links:

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message
- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the role to the person who used it, you should get the message member and give it.

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    var roles = message.author.roles
    let roleID = '779756792737300490';
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ttt')) {
        message.member.roles.add(roleID);          
    }
});
```

I just changed the 6th line.

You also can't give a role to a user. You can only give it to a member.

You can also take a look at docs:

- Member: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=member
- User: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    var guildMember = message.member
    let roleID = '779756792737300490';
    let roleNAME = 'TestRole';
    let userID = message.author.tag + " " + (message.author.id);
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ttt')) {
        guildMember.roles.add(roleID); 
        console.log(`Give "${roleNAME}" to User "${userID}" `)    
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "zzz")) {
        guildMember.roles.remove(roleID);
        console.log(`Removed "${roleNAME}" from User "${userID}"`)
    }
});
```

I also put a console.log code in it, so you can see if somebody removed a role or gave a role, it will also work if you remove the 2 lines of Code ;)